# Trying to create multiple google map markers in dynamic map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have created a map with some links, which (when clicked) change the maps location using jquery.

I have tried to implement a marker for each location, but stuggling to get the markers to show on any other map location other than the one set as default.

I am trying to set up a marker for each lat and long value. I have tried to use the following code but I get the error: TypeError: map.setPosition is not a function in firebug console.

My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<a id="link-aberdeen" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button1">Munich</a>    
<a id="link-glasgow" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button2">Oxford</a>    
<a id="link-glasgow" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button3">Glasgow</a>   

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map-canvas { background: #eaeaea none repeat scroll 0 0; height: 300px; width: 100%; }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function initialize() {

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954,12.556663), //Setting Initial Position
zoom: 10
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954,12.556663),
center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954,12.556663),
zoom: 10
});

}


function newLocation(newLat,newLng) {
map.setCenter({
    lat : newLat,
    lng : newLng
});

map.setPosition({
    lat : newLat,
    lng : newLng
});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


$(document).ready(function () {

$(".button1").on('click', function () {
  newLocation(48.1293954,12.556663);
});

$(".button2").on('click', function () {
  newLocation(51.7163950,-1.2196100);
});

$(".button3").on('click', function () {
  newLocation(55.8610240,-4.2614560);
});

});
```

I also have a fiddle I have been testing on, please see https://jsfiddle.net/xxfairydragonxx/7j31df1v/

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I couldn't make this to work in Fiddle...
But it works in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ObJRLz?editors=1010).

I fixed many small things.

1. Use `initialize` instead of `initMap` in the google API script call callback...
   Since that's how you named your function.
2. Declare `map` as global (outside a specific function).
3. All that is regarding the map should be inside the `initialize function`.
4. And don't forget to load jQuery if you use it for thing like your 3 links !!!

The code:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954, 12.556663), //Setting Initial Position
        zoom: 10
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954, 12.556663),
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1293954, 12.556663),
        zoom: 10
    });

    function newLocation(newLat, newLng) {
        map.setCenter({
            lat: newLat,
            lng: newLng
        });

        new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position:{
                lat: newLat,
                lng: newLng
            }
        });
    }


    $(".button1").on('click', function() {
        newLocation(48.1293954, 12.556663);
    });
    $(".button2").on('click', function() {
        newLocation(51.7163950, -1.2196100);
    });
    $(".button3").on('click', function() {
        newLocation(55.8610240, -4.2614560);
    });

}
```

The API call:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7_p0NkDTQQmn8ZVJosJJ-3Xr93x-tVVo&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `setCenter` method on your map instance on button click as well `setPosition` on the marker instance. Your example does not work because of function scope. Your `marker` is scoped to the `initialize` function. You either have to remove the `var` before `marker` to hoist to to the `global` / `window` object or create a variable declaration outside your `initialize` function.

```
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(…);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker(…);
}

$('.button').on('click', function() {
  map.setCenter({
    lat: LATITUDE,
    lng: LONGITUDE
  });

 marker.setPosition({
    lat: LATITUDE,
    lng: LONGITUDE
 });
});
```